# Export-Csv Producing Empty Output File

Tags: powershell

I've got a script to audit local user accounts. Everything works, except exporting to CSV. The output file is blank, except for the column headers:

| Computer | Name | Enabled | PasswordChangeableDate | PasswordExpires | UserMayChangePassword | PasswordRequired | PasswordLastSet | LastLogon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

What am I doing wrong here? The export portion is towards the bottom.

```
$Result = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object] #store local user data
$Errors = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object] #store any devices that could not be reached

$devices = Get-Content "list.txt" #read in all devices to check

#for progress bar - store current # and total
$length = $devices.Count
$i = 1

$displayOutputReport = $true

foreach ($device in $devices){
    Write-Progress -Activity "Retrieving data from $device ($i of $length)" -percentComplete  ($i++*100/$length) -status Running

    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $device -Count 1 -Quiet){
        #Get account properties and add to list

         $temp = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $device -ScriptBlock {
             Get-LocalUser |  Select-Object -Property @{N="Computer"; E={$env:COMPUTERNAME}}, Name, Enabled, PasswordChangeableDate, PasswordExpires, UserMayChangePassword, PasswordRequired, PasswordLastSet, LastLogon
         }
         $Result.Add($temp)

    }else{
        $errors.Add($device)
        Write-Host "Cannot connect to $device, skipping." -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}

#display results
if ($displayOutputReport){
    if ($Result.Count -gt 0){
        $Result | Format-Table Computer,Name, Enabled, PasswordChangeableDate, PasswordExpires, UserMayChangePassword, PasswordRequired, PasswordLastSet, LastLogon -AutoSize
    }

    Write-Host ""

    if ($Errors.Count -gt 0){
        Write-Host "Errors:" -ForegroundColor Red
        $Errors
        Write-Host ""
    }
}

#export to CSV
$ScriptPath = $pwd.Path
$ReportDate = (Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy hh-mm-ss tt')

if($Result.Count -gt 0){
    $reportFile = $ScriptPath + "\LocalUserAudit $ReportDate.csv"
    $Result | Select-Object Computer, Name, Enabled, PasswordChangeableDate, PasswordExpires, UserMayChangePassword, PasswordRequired, PasswordLastSet, LastLogon | Export-Csv $reportFile -NotypeInformation
    Write-Host "Report saved to $reportFile"
}

if ($Errors.Count -gt 0){
    $errorFile = $ScriptPath + "\LocalUserAudit ERRORS $ReportDate.txt"
    $Errors | Out-File $errorFile
    Write-Host "Errors saved to $errorFile"
}
```

Comment: If you just `Out-File` it, do you get all rows?

Comment: No luck. It repeats the column headers 4 times vertically (since that's the # of devices in my test list.txt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```sh
$Result.Add($temp)
```

to

```sh
$Result.AddRange(@($temp))
```

to ensure that `$Result` ends up as a *flat* collection of objects.

---

As for **what you tried**:

`$temp` is likely to be an *array* of objects, as `Get-LocalUser` likely reports *multiple* users.

I you pass an *array* to [`` List`1.Add() ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.List-1.Add), it is added *as a whole* to the list, which is not your intent.

Therefore you ended up with a list of *arrays* rather than a flat list of *individual objects*. And because an *array* doesn't have the properties you were trying to select (`Name`, `Enabled`, ...) the column values for those properties in the output CSV ended up empty.

By contrast, [`` List`1.AddRange() ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.List-1.Add) accepts an *enumerable* of objects (which an array implicitly is), and adds each enumerated object *directly* to the list.

The use of `@(...)` around `$temp` guards against the case where `Get-LocalUser` happens to return just *one* object - `@()`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), then ensures that it is treated *as an array*.

---

**A better alternative**:

If you use the `foreach` loop *as an expression*, you can let *PowerShell* do the work of collecting all output objects in flat array, thanks to the pipeline's automatic enumeration of collections:

```sh
# Assign directly to $Result
$Result = foreach ($device in $devices){
    Write-Progress -Activity "Retrieving data from $device ($i of $length)" -percentComplete  ($i++*100/$length) -status Running

    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $device -Count 1 -Quiet){
        #Get account properties and add to list

         # Simply pass the output of the Invoke-Command call through.
         Invoke-Command -ComputerName $device -ScriptBlock {
             Get-LocalUser |  Select-Object -Property @{N="Computer"; E={$env:COMPUTERNAME}}, Name, Enabled, PasswordChangeableDate, PasswordExpires, UserMayChangePassword, PasswordRequired, PasswordLastSet, LastLogon
         }

    }else{
        $errors.Add($device)
        Write-Host "Cannot connect to $device, skipping." -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

This is not only more convenient, but also performs better.

Note: If you need to ensure that `$Result` is always an array, use `[array] $Result = foreach ...`

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I've got it working, **but** can someone explain why this works instead? I'd prefer to avoid concatenating arrays when this will be run thousands of times.

I changed

```
$Result = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
```

to

```
$Result = @()
```

And

```
$temp = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $device -ScriptBlock {
         Get-LocalUser |  Select-Object -Property @{N="Computer"; E={$env:COMPUTERNAME}}, Name, Enabled, PasswordChangeableDate, PasswordExpires, UserMayChangePassword, PasswordRequired, PasswordLastSet, LastLogon
     }
     $Result.Add($temp)
```

To

```
 $Result += Invoke-Command -ComputerName $device -ScriptBlock {
         Get-LocalUser |  Select-Object -Property @{N="Computer"; E={$env:COMPUTERNAME}}, Name, Enabled, PasswordChangeableDate, PasswordExpires, UserMayChangePassword, PasswordRequired, PasswordLastSet, LastLogon
    }
```

Comment: As for why `+=` with an array works: `+`, when applied to two arrays performs _element-wise_ concatenation, so that `1,2  + 3, 4` creates a new, flat array `1, 2, 3, 4`.

Comment: That said, iteratively building up arrays with `+=` should be avoided for performance reasons, and simply using a `foreach` loop to let PowerShell collect all outputs in an array is both more convenient and much faster: see the bottom section of the accepted answer and, for more details, including performance measurements,  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/45375).

Comment: In general, if you want to avoid the penalties of copying in memory, you can append incremental data to a file.